# How to connect Google Datastore from a script in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

We want to do some stuff with the data that is in the Google Datastore. We have a database already, We would like to use Python 3 to handle the data and make queries from a script on our developing machines. Which would be the easiest way to accomplish what we need?

Comment: Google publishes examples of how to use Datastore in Python. The solution is to read the documentation. Here is one to start with: https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From the [Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python):**

> 1. You will need to install the Cloud Datastore client library for Python:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-datastore
```

> 2. Set up authentication by creating a service account and setting an environment variable. It will be easier if you see it, please take a look at the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python) for more info about this. You can perform this step by either using the GCP console or command line.
> 3. Then you will be able to connect to your Cloud Datastore client and use it, as in the example below:

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import datastore

# Instantiates a client
datastore_client = datastore.Client()

# The kind for the new entity
kind = 'Task'
# The name/ID for the new entity
name = 'sampletask1'
# The Cloud Datastore key for the new entity
task_key = datastore_client.key(kind, name)

# Prepares the new entity
task = datastore.Entity(key=task_key)
task['description'] = 'Buy milk'

# Saves the entity
datastore_client.put(task)

print('Saved {}: {}'.format(task.key.name, task['description']))
```

> As @JohnHanley mentioned, you will find a good example on this [Bookshelf app tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore) that uses Cloud Datastore to store its persistent data and metadata for books.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service account and download the credentials as JSON and then set an environment variable called GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS pointing to the json file. You can see the details at the link below.

https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html